# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django

Hola tengo un error en mi codigo de python django. El error es `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. Alguien me podría ayudar ya que no he encontrado la solución.

Este es mi código:

## Models.py

```
class Evento(models.Model):
    Nombre_evento        = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    ubicacion            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    inicio_evento        = models.DateField(blank=False)
    hora_inicio_evento   = models.TimeField()
    Fin_evento           = models.DateField(blank=False)
    hora_fin_evento      = models.TimeField()
    Descripcion_evento   = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
```

## forms.py:

```
class RawEventoForm(forms.Form):
    Nombre_evento        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '60', "placeholder": "Escribir aquí"}))
    ubicacion            = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '60', "placeholder": "Escribir aquí"}), label="<br> Ubicacion")
    inicio_evento        = forms.DateField(widget = DateInput, label="<br> Inicio evento")
    hora_inicio_evento   = forms.TimeField(widget = TimeInput, label="<br> Hora inicio evento")
    Fin_evento           = forms.DateField(widget = DateInput, label="<br> Fin evento")
    hora_fin_evento      = forms.TimeField(widget = TimeInput, label="<br> Hora fin evento")
    Descripcion_evento   = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "new-class-name two", "rows":5, 'cols':60, "placeholder": "Escribir aquí"}), label="<br> Descripcion evento")
```

Comment: Hola Yercko, ¿podrías incluir más información del error (Traceback)?

Comment: Como no sea que los valores 5 y 60 de los campos "rows" y "cols" deban ir entre comillas...

Comment: @DiegoPinilla te explico, cuando quiero dirigirme a mi modelo de eventos en el admin de django me aparece el error de `OperationalError at /admin/Escuela/evento/
no such column: Escuela_evento.hora_inicio_evento` entonces dado a esto busque la solución a este problema y me dice que tengo que realizar un migrate y makemigrations, el cual hice un migrate y me aparece el error de `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` dado a esto necesito buscar la solución del migrate para asi solucionar el primer problema que me aparecio.

Comment: @abulafia intente hacer eso que dijiste y no hay solución, yo creo que el error esta en el campo hora_inicio_evento ya que el primer problema que me aparecio fue ese y dado a eso tuve que hacer un migrate.

Comment: @DiegoPinilla ahi otro dato si es que aun estas en duda, aparece esto arriba de mi error `match = time_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`